# ADALM 1000 hardware schematic

Tags: pcb-design

I don't know if it is the correct forum to ask this kind of question

I have a circuit board from Analog Electronics.  Its model number is ADALM1000.  Its DigiKey part number is 505-ADALM1000-ND.

I am looking for its full PCB schematic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Schematics are at the bottom of this page
https://wiki.analog.com/university/tools/m1k/hw